# SVG (using React Simple Maps) not displaying on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, maps

Hello (first time posting on Stack Overflow, so apologies for any breaches in etiquette...)

I'm currently building a React app that contains an interactive SVG map built using [React Simple Maps](https://www.react-simple-maps.io/). Everything is working as expected in my desktop browser, however the map itself does not load on mobile devices (I've tested several) and I can't figure out why. I've included the code from the component in question below (I've removed some irrelevant parts of the code):

```
import React, { memo, Component } from 'react';
import { ZoomableGroup, ComposableMap, Geographies, Geography } from "react-simple-maps";
import geoUrl from "../data/topo.json";
import Country from './Country'
import { CSSTransition, SwitchTransition } from "react-transition-group";

class Map extends Component { 

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            country: "",
            dish: "",
            description: "",
            photo: "",
            recipe: "",
            selected: false,
        }

        this.handleBack = this.handleBack.bind(this);
        this.handleAbout = this.handleAbout.bind(this);
        this.handleList = this.handleList.bind(this);
    }

    handleEnter(country, dish, description, photo, recipe){
        this.setState({
            country: country,
            dish: dish,
            description: description,
            photo: photo,
            recipe: recipe
        })
    }
    
    render(){ 
    
        const { country, dish, description, photo, recipe, selected } = this.state;
        const countries = geoUrl.objects.ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geometries;

        return(
            <SwitchTransition>
                <CSSTransition
                    classNames="transition"
                    transitionAppearTimeout={50000}
                    key={ selected }
                    in={ selected }
                    unmountOnExit
                    appear
                >         
                    <> 
                        <section className="map">
                            <div className="container">
                                <ComposableMap width="1200" data-tip="" projectionConfig={{ scale: 200 }} >
                                    <ZoomableGroup>
                                        <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
                                            {({ geographies }) =>
                                                geographies.map(geo =>
                                                    <a href="#country">
                                                        <Geography 
                                                            key={geo.rsmKey} 
                                                            geography={geo}
                                                            onMouseEnter={() => {
                                                                const { NAME } = geo.properties;
                                                                this.props.setTooltipContent(`${NAME}`);
                                                            }}
                                                            onMouseLeave={() => {
                                                                this.props.setTooltipContent("");
                                                            }}
                                                            onClick={() => {
                                                                const { NAME, DISH, DESCRIPTION, PHOTO, RECIPE } = geo.properties;
                                                                this.handleEnter(NAME, DISH, DESCRIPTION, PHOTO, RECIPE);
                                                            }}
                                                            fill="#44BBA4"
                                                            stroke="#E94F37"
                                                            strokeWidth="0.5"
                                                            style={{
                                                                default: {
                                                                    outline: 'none'
                                                                },
                                                                hover: {
                                                                    fill: "#E94F37",
                                                                    outline: 'none'
                                                                },
                                                                pressed: {
                                                                    outline: 'none'
                                                                }
                                                            }}
                                                        />
                                                    </a>
                                                )
                                            }
                                        </Geographies>
                                    </ZoomableGroup>
                                </ComposableMap>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </>
                </CSSTransition>
            </SwitchTransition>
        );
    }
}

export default memo(Map);
```

If anyone might have any insights that would be fantastic! Please let me know if you would like to see more code/screenshots etc. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,
try to change the width 
from 
<ComposableMap width="1200"
 to 
<ComposableMap style={{ width: "100%" }}>

Comment: @Maitham thank you! If I removed the width="1200" property and replaced it with style={{width: "100%"}} the map did not render at all on mobile or desktop, however by having BOTH of the properties on ComposableMap that seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: that's weird two widths !! 
anyway you are welcome and good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Maitham for helping me fine the answer - by adding a property of `style={{width: "100%"}}` to `<ComposableMap>`, the issue now seems to be resolved! This SHOULD NOT replace the `width="1200"` property (if you remove this the map will not render at all on mobile or desktop), but should be in addition to it:

```
<ComposableMap width="1200" style={{ width: "100%" }} data-tip="" projectionConfig={{ scale: 200 }} >
```